# Autocomplete for all words in a string

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Based upon a string is it possible to create an autocomplete for all the words in that string?

For example: String str="Wave supports Robots and Gadgets. Wave robot development requires Java 1.6. A wave can be seen as an envelop which contains wavelets"

Now if the user enters **Wave** in the input text box, in the dropdown it should show: "**Wave supports**", "**Wave robot**" and "**wave can**".

In short it should show the next word besides the typed word.

Comment: Yes this is possible. You want to write this yourself? Looking for something someone else already made? Just guidance?

Comment: If you are using MS SQL Server You may have a look at FullText catalog search options.

Comment: Just some pointers about how to get started

Comment: do you make use of the jquery ui autocomplete widget?

Comment: Look into Markov chains. They are a way of a system learning which words generally follow which other words, so with that you could list the words that are most likely to come next at the top.

Comment: +1 for Markov chains, that's exactly what I thought when I read the title.

Answer (score 1):

Some pointers to get you started.

1. Split the string to list of words using for example `List<string> words = new List<string>(sData.Split(' '));`
2. Iterate the words using ordinary `for (int i = 0; i < words.Count...` loop and when the current item in the loop is equal to given input, add `words[i] + words[i + 1]` to a List that is initially empty let's call it `matches`.
3. Send `matches` to the browser, for example delimeted by `|` character: `Response.Write(string.Join("|"), matches);`
4. In the calling JS, parse the result in the `success` method of the AJAX and for each possible match build one line user can select.

Comment: or if he is using jquery ui just pass it as `array` into the `source:` option. ;) +1

Answer (score 1):

I did this with the jQuery Autocomplete.

I returned (from my database) a multiple set of possible answers.

Based on what was typed, I had groups of priority in my returned list, sorted alpha within that subsection of list.  Groups were:

- Exact match - strings with an exact match
- Begins with - strings that begin with the entered words
- Contains - broke down the list for words, then return that list.

I made it so that the words in the return list within the entered set were **highlighted within the return results list**.  My return results listed the entire string with a match, with bold on the matched words.

You could easily use a your "word plus" approach to match strings with a word, plus the next word for each of a list of words as you describe - probably this would be applied between the "Begins" and "Contains" groups in my strategy but yours might differ.

From a performance standpoint, I was only using about 10,000 strings (up to 255 characters each) as a possible result set and only returned a limited set (say 50 "best matches" from the original sample of strings.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a trie-like datastructure. A trie is tree-like-binary-tree and makes searching in a dictionary very fast and simple. Most likely a trie is used to store words and not a couple of words but I guess you can still use a trie to finish your task. For example you can make a first trie with just words of your sentence. Then you make a 2nd trie with 2 words of your sentence and so on. Now you have to lookup in each trie to autocomplete the user's input.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible if you have the whole word stored in a data source[database etc] somewhere. Do check out jQuery autocomplete or just search for autocomplete javascript plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Create a tree with expanding letter combinations

> "Err sorry i never read his whole question ... I suppose it could be adapted for words"

```
function wordTree(){
var WT = this;

WT.tree = {};

    WT.word = function(word){
        var current = WT.tree;
        for(var i = 0;i < word.length; i ++){
            var check = current[word[i ]];
            if(!check){ 
                current = current[word[i]] = {value: word.substr(0,i +1), words: [word]};
            }else{
                current = check;
                current.words_ahead.push(word);
            }
        }

    }
    WT.getWords = function(base){
        var current = WT.tree;
        for(var i = 0;i < base.length; i ++){
            var check = current[base[i]];
            if(check){
                current = check;
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
        return current.words;

    }
}
```

Now create base tree

```
var tt = new wordTree();
```

Add all your words

```
tt.word("word");
tt.word("about");
tt.word("after");
tt.word("again");
tt.word("air");
tt.word("all");
tt.word("along");
tt.word("also");
tt.word("an");
tt.word("and");
tt.word("another");
tt.word("any");
tt.word("are");
tt.word("around");
tt.word("as");
tt.word("at");
tt.word("away");
tt.word("back");
tt.word("be");
tt.word("because");
tt.word("been");
tt.word("before");
tt.word("below");
tt.word("between");
tt.word("both");
tt.word("but");
tt.word("by");
tt.word("came");
tt.word("can");
tt.word("come");
tt.word("could");
tt.word("day");
tt.word("did");
tt.word("different");
tt.word("do");
tt.word("does");
tt.word("don");
tt.word("t");
tt.word("down");
tt.word("each");
tt.word("end");
tt.word("even");
tt.word("every");
tt.word("few");
tt.word("find");
tt.word("first");
tt.word("for");
tt.word("found");
tt.word("from");
tt.word("get");
tt.word("give");
tt.word("go");
tt.word("good");
tt.word("great");
tt.word("had");
tt.word("has");
tt.word("have");
tt.word("he");
tt.word("help");
tt.word("her");
tt.word("here");
tt.word("him");
tt.word("his");
tt.word("home");
tt.word("house");
tt.word("how");
tt.word("I");
tt.word("if");
tt.word("in");
tt.word("into");
tt.word("is");
tt.word("it");
tt.word("its");
tt.word("just");
tt.word("know");
tt.word("large");
tt.word("last");
tt.word("left");
tt.word("like");
tt.word("line");
tt.word("little");
tt.word("long");
tt.word("look");
tt.word("made");
tt.word("make");
tt.word("man");
tt.word("many");
tt.word("may");
tt.word("me");
tt.word("men");
tt.word("might");
tt.word("more");
tt.word("most");
tt.word("Mr");
tt.word("must");
tt.word("my");
tt.word("name");
tt.word("never");
tt.word("new");
tt.word("next");
tt.word("no");
tt.word("not");
tt.word("now");
tt.word("number");
tt.word("of");
tt.word("off");
tt.word("old");
tt.word("on");
tt.word("one");
tt.word("only");
tt.word("or");
tt.word("other");
tt.word("our");
tt.word("out");
tt.word("over");
tt.word("own");
tt.word("part");
tt.word("people");
tt.word("place");
tt.word("put");
tt.word("read");
tt.word("right");
tt.word("said");
tt.word("same");
tt.word("saw");
tt.word("say");
tt.word("see");
tt.word("she");
tt.word("should");
tt.word("show");
tt.word("small");
tt.word("so");
tt.word("some");
tt.word("something");
tt.word("sound");
tt.word("still");
tt.word("such");
tt.word("take");
tt.word("tell");
tt.word("than");
tt.word("that");
tt.word("the");
tt.word("them");
tt.word("then");
tt.word("there");
tt.word("these");
tt.word("they");
tt.word("thing");
tt.word("think");
tt.word("this");
tt.word("those");
tt.word("thought");
tt.word("three");
tt.word("through");
tt.word("time");
tt.word("to");
tt.word("together");
tt.word("too");
tt.word("two");
tt.word("under");
tt.word("up");
tt.word("us");
tt.word("use");
tt.word("very");
tt.word("want");
tt.word("water");
tt.word("way");
tt.word("we");
tt.word("well");
tt.word("went");
tt.word("were");
tt.word("what");
tt.word("when");
tt.word("where");
tt.word("which");
tt.word("while");
tt.word("who");
tt.word("why");
tt.word("will");
tt.word("with");
tt.word("word");
tt.word("work");
tt.word("world");
tt.word("would");
tt.word("write");
tt.word("year");
tt.word("you");
tt.word("your");
```

search for anything statring with "wo"

```
tt.getWords("wo");
```

chrome console outputs something like this

```
Object {item_value: "wo", words: Array[5], r: Object, u: Object}
    item_value: "wo"
    r: Object
    u: Object
    words_ahead: Array[5]
        0: "word"
        1: "word"
        2: "work"
        3: "world"
        4: "would"
        length: 5
__proto__: Array[0]
__proto__: Object
```